# I'm using django and beautiful soup trying to get the links but it's not working

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape data using beautiful soup and django. I'm using B.S. In conjunction with requests. There are 38 links on the page but when I try to output them only one shows. Heres my code in views.py

```
def sewp(request):
r = requests.get("http://www.vladtv.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find_all("a")

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    link = link.get("href")

ella = "ella"
context = {
    "link": link,
    "ella": ella,
}
return render(request, "posts/display_soup.html", context)
```

but if I do this

```
def sewp(request):
r = requests.get("http://www.vladtv.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find_all("a")

ella = "ella"
context = {
    "content": content,
    "ella": ella,
}
return render(request, "posts/display_soup.html", context)
```

all the links show
How can I correct my code to make this work? Any guidance is welcomed. there really is no documentation or tutorials that explain how to use B.S. and Django.
I've been using Django less than a month and have started using B.S. and Requests 12 hours ago. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the loop of your code. The value of link gets replaced after every iteration. Hence, at the end of the loop only one link is printed (the last link).

You need to initialize a list and then append the links into it. Then pass that list to the context.

```
links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(link.get("href"))

# Or you could simplify that loop using list comprehension:
# links = [link.get("href") for link in soup.find_all('a')]

context = {
    "links": links
}
```

Comment: Trying it the second way you posted I get the following error NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: it worked You capitalized the "A" in find_All. it should be find_all. This way looks way cleaner. Do you know How I could put each one on a seperate line. I tried prettify earlier tonite and it didn't work

Comment: use `for` loop to print list/dictionary elements in separated lines

Comment: @losee - See [The Django template system chapter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html) of the django book for more information. You'll have to loop through the array and then display each value in the template i.e. `display_soup.html`.